# Handle database that can change in Android app?

Tags: android, database, api

I want to create a database for an Android app. It is likely to get changes over time (new data added every so often).

I can call a web API and change the data on a server rather than on each client's device. The problem is that this would require people to be connected to fetch the data (or is it a problem?).

Should I create a database on the server and allow the client to copy everything (notify him of an update when he is connected to internet) so that it can work offline?

What is generally done in such a case? This app should be used outside, obviously I don't want people to be limited by their mobile data. Advice very much appreciated.

Comment: Generally the device will call a RESTful service (I think you have this with the web API) and then stores the data locally (i.e. on the device) in a SQLite database.

Comment: This is one option, [sync adapters](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)

Comment: @RickS I like this. Clean and suited to my needs. Ty

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create a database on the server and allow the client to copy everything (notify him of an update when he is connected to internet) so that it can work offline?

Yes, it's okay to go with this approach. I would like to brief a little more which I have done in one of my projects.

1. Create method A, B, C. Keep a separate boolean field in your server, which you must set true if any new data has been added.
2. Method_A() - Fetch data from your local storage and show them in your app.
3. Method_B() - Fetch data from server and save them in your local storage.

Now you can apply the steps.

```
if(internetIsPresent){
    Boolean hasNewData = check_boolean_field_in_your_server;
    if(hasNewData){
        Method_B();
    } else {
        Method_A();
    }
} else{
    Method_A();
}
```